# Why does this code for zipping a folder create an evergrowing file only when called in a specific place

Tags: java, android

i use this code to create a zip of the contents of the application data folder

```
public static void zipFolder(File inputFolder) {
    try {
        File srcFile = inputFolder;
        File[] files = srcFile.listFiles();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(inputFolder, "toSend.zip"));
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        Log.d("", "Zip directory: " + srcFile.getName());

        for (File file : files) {
            Log.d("", "Adding file: " + file.getName());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("", ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

when calling it in regular code it works fine, however i want to run this when the application crashes along with other logging code i run inside an overridden Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

in this case the file is created but it keeps growing indefinitely until i force close the application

when following the flow with the debugger i see the files being zipped (File[] files) are just those i expect and i manage to get out of the function call (on to execute the following code) so i don't think it's the function falling into an endless loop

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        //here and anywhere else in the code it manages to create a valid zip file with the folder contents
        File toZip = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        MyUtils.zipFolder(toZip);

        if (Costanti.SETTINGS_MAKE_CRASH_LOG)
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
            {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    File logFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null);

                    Log.d("Dump logcat from UncaughtExceptionHandler");
                    String filepath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/logcat.txt";
                    String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filepath;
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                    } catch (IOException ee) {
                        Log.d("Dump skipped");
                    }

                    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

                    File file = new File(logFolder, "LOG-"+ MyUtils.getTSsemicompact());

                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                        myOutWriter.append(errors.toString());
                        myOutWriter.close();
                        fOut.close();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    File toZip = getExternalFilesDir(null);
                    MyUtils.zipFolder(toZip);

                    //calling this because otherwise it would just stay stuck on the broken activity where the crash occurred
                    System.exit(0);//when debugging i can reach this line
                }
            });
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are invoking this method?